# Unable to store data in a matrix

Tags: r, loops

I am using the following code to check P-values of a linear trend, but it seems that the loop is not working properly as I cannot see a 2-D map of P-value but only a row

```
library(chron)
library(RColorBrewer)
library(lattice)
library(ncdf4)
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
options(warn=-1)

ncin <- nc_open("MOD04_10K_Winter.nc", readunlim=FALSE)
#print(ncin)
lon <- ncvar_get(ncin, varid="Longitude", start=NA, count=NA, verbose=FALSE,
          signedbyte=TRUE, collapse_degen=TRUE, raw_datavals=FALSE )
lat <- ncvar_get(ncin, varid="Latitude", start=NA, count=NA, verbose=FALSE,
                signedbyte=TRUE, collapse_degen=TRUE, raw_datavals=FALSE )
aod <- ncvar_get(ncin, varid="AOD", start=NA, count=NA, verbose=FALSE,
                signedbyte=TRUE, collapse_degen=TRUE, raw_datavals=FALSE )

px           <- matrix(nrow = 1:length(lon), ncol = 1:length(lat))
is.matrix(px)

for (lo in 1:length(lon)) {
  for (la in 1:length(lat)) {
   int1a    = aod[lo, la,]

   # if mean of int is finite then proceed else fill NA to all arrays
   mn = mean(int1a, trim = 0, na.rm = FALSE)
   if (is.finite(mn)) 
    {
    print("---------------- Reading Finite data -------------")
    xs       = 1:30                                     
    fn1a     = lm(int1a~xs)       # Function_NCP
    p_val    = summary(fn1a)$coefficients[2, 4]          # Saving p-value
    if (p_val < 0.05) {print("statisticlly significant")} else {print("statisticlly in-significant")}
    print(p_val)
    print(lo)
    print(la)
    px[lo][la] = p_val                                   # variables in [] only (?)
   } 

  }                                                      # latitude dimension
}
```

If I am using `[lo, la]` instead of `[lo][la]` I am having the following error

> Error in `[<-`(`*tmp*`, lo, la, value = 0.0543481042240582) :
>   subscript out of bounds

Sorry if the solution is very trivial, I have just started working in R.

Comment: This just means that somewhere, in one of the `px[]` a number is going in that doesn't correspond to anything in `px`. Try checking the extreme values on the for loop (ie the first number that gets run through and the last) as they are usually the cause of problems like this. Also if you want more detailed help make your answer reproducible

Answer (score 0):

You have just to make a small fix on the matrix `px` declaration. Now you set the number of rows and columns as vectors: `nrow = 1:length(lon)` and `nrow = 1:length(lon)`. R silently takes only the first elements of these vectors and generates a 1 to 1 matrix. (Actually, it would generate a warning, by the warnings are supressed!)

So, the solution is

```
px <- matrix(nrow = length(lon), ncol = length(lat))
```